# What to do in Java to make a while loop execute if return statement from method doesn't comply?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MethHead
{

    public static int calMe(int a, int b)
    {
        int sum=a+b;
        return sum;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
       do
       {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers to add");
        System.out.println("a: ");
        int a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("b: ");
        int b=input.nextInt();
        int sum=calMe(a, b);
        }   
        while(sum!=2);
    }
}
```

Ok, stupid question, but alwell.  I keep getting

> cannot find symbol- variable sum

I'm trying to figure out how to position a loop to continue the program if a certain value is returned from the method.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Declare sum outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

declare variable sum outside the loop

```
int sum; 
       do
       {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers to add");
        System.out.println("a: ");
        int a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("b: ");
        int b=input.nextInt();
        sum= calMe(a, b);
        }   
        while(sum!=2);
```

Comment: when I do that it shoots me this
"variable sum is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: @CarolineHightower you declare variable  sum inside the 'do'. you need to use variable out side the 'do'. variable must declared outside the loop for using other places. & pardon my language

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MethHead
{

```
public static int calMe(int a, int b)
{
    int sum=a+b;
    return sum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int sum;
   do
   {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers to add");
    System.out.println("a: ");
    int a=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("b: ");
    int b=input.nextInt();
    sum=calMe(a, b);
    }   
    while(sum!=2);
}
```

}

How I fixed it... just in case anyone ever comes across the same problem.